# Android 4 Drag & Drop horizontally

Tags: android

I am able to drag n drop items successfully with View.startDrag method.

But I want to restrict dragging only by X axis with some Y axis offset.
Currently when user started dragging he is able to move that view anywhere on the screen so how can I limit appearance of dragging so user will not be able to move it up and down.

Thank you.

Comment: have you done this? please share the answer if yes

Comment: Hi, unfortunately android doesn't allow you to implement this...

Comment: What is the aletrnative solution... my exact question is http://stackoverflow.com/q/19649023/1538399